# "Fill Weekdays" in excel 2010 fills sunday to friday

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have an excel sheet, in which I filled the date 01/03/2013.

I used the autofill feature to fill in the weekdays only, but excel filled Sunday to Friday, instead of Sunday to Thursday.

Any way to change that?

Comment: Should it fill Monday to Friday?

Comment: No, Sunday to Thursday - that's the work week in Israel.

Comment: Would you like a macro where you put in the first date and it fills in the date plus 4, skips 2, fills 5, etc?

Comment: @jbkkd ahh i see, well lets just fill Monday - Tuesday..now thats a workweek.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Go to the `developer tab` (`file - options - customize ribbon -` check `developer tab` on the right) and `addins - Analysis toolpack`</strike>
Once you do this, type in your first date (A1 for instance) as a Sunday
below that use the formula `=workday.intl(A1,1,7)` and drag it down. It will give you Sunday through Thursday. [more info on workday function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/starter-help/workday-intl-function-HA010354380.aspx)

edit - I think for 2010 it's included as a regular function.

Comment: +1 FYI WORKDAY.INTL is only available in Excel 2010 - it isn't part of Analysis ToolPak - in earlier versions you can do the same by manipulating WORKDAY, i.e. `=WORKDAY(A1+1,1)-1` - Note WORKDAY `is` part of Analysis ToolPak in Excel 2003 and earlier, in 2007 and later it's built-in

Comment: @barryhoudini Good info, thanks. I had never used workday.intl before, but it seems pretty useful

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with Windows regional settings.
Excel should get the information on weekdays from there.
Check if Regional settings in Control Panel is set to use standards for Israel.